# How to load asyncronaly other resources different than model for a page with ember

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have a page with a table that list orders, so i have in my `OrdersIndexRoute`

```
model: function(){
    return this.get('store').query('order', {...});
}
```

Having that an order belongs to a product i want to add a select to filter orders for a selected product

I can have the products by calling `this.get('store').query('product', {...});` but not sure what would be the proper place to do it, i think it's in the `OrdersIndexController` but that's just my guess, maybe this could be placed in the route activate hook but don't know how to access it from controller, maybe there is a pattern for this kind of case but i have not found a good example or guide for it and how to do this avoiding to recall products every time the model gets reloaded.

Any help will be appreciated, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a Ember.RSVP.hash in your hook model in order to load multiple async resources before your route is displayed :

```
model() {
  return Ember.RSVP.hash({
    orders: this.get('store').query('order', {...}),
    products: this.get('store').query('product', {...})
  });
}
```

and later, instead of calling directly this.get('model'), you will call this.get('model.orders') or this.get('model.products')

Comment: the problem with that is it will make the products request every time the model is reloaded due to a queryParam change like sort_by=field, i was doing that exactly previously but every time i changed the sort_by query param the model function was requesting the orders as well the products which is not needed